# Execute javascript function from java

Tags: java, javascript, android

I want to know if it's possible to execute a javascript function from java. Basically I have a javascript function to which I want to pass a string and then get the output from that function.

If it's possible, how do I accomplish it?

EDIT -

I couldn't find a solution to this, what I did was re-write all the javascript code in Java. But I am guessing, Rhino ported on Android should do the trick. If someone has tried it out, please post a solution.

Comment: you also tagged android, is it on your android device you want to call a JS function?

Comment: Please don't tag your questions in the title, that's what the normal tags are for.

Comment: but it's misleading. thanks anyhow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript is not natively supported in java. If you need it, you may implement the [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/download.html) javascript engine to do this.

*"Rhino is an open-source implementation of JavaScript written entirely in Java. It is typically embedded into Java applications to provide scripting to end users."*

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to take a look at the [ScriptEngine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html). There are plenty of samples out there on how to use it. Works on anything but Mac where they for some reason selected to include AppleScript instead of JavaScript by default.

*Edit:* Take a look at [this page](http://divineprogrammer.blogspot.com/2009/11/javascript-rhino-on-android.html), there seems to be a Rhino port for Android out there.

Comment: Probably not (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454425), Technically Android doesn't have a JVM but a DalvikVM. I don't know if the ScriptEngine is part of that but I guess it would be possible to bring Rhino over (which is what it is based on) if not,